# Two database connection strings in app.config with EF code first approach causing error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have code first entity model designed and working fine as follows:

```
 <add name="DemoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DemoDataModel.csdl|res://*/DemoDataModel.ssdl|res://*/DemoDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;          
         provider connection string=&quot;data source=myservername;initial catalog=DemoDB;user id=demouser;password=abcd123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

    <add name="SecondDemoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SecondDemoDataModel.csdl|res://*/SecondDemoDataModel.ssdl|res://*/SecondDemoDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;          
         provider connection string=&quot;data source=myservername;initial catalog=SecondDemoDB;user id=demouser;password=abcd123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

But first connection string is working fine and i am able to read the data. But second connection string is throwing following error:

''A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Run time error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.''

Please help, I have done this:
Used separate entity files and declared them in the constructors:

```
        public Application1Entities()
            : base("DemoEntities")
        {

        }


           public Application2Entities()
                : base("SecondDemoEntities")
            {

            }
```

Comment: Can you connect with those same credentials from Sql Server Management studio?

Comment: Yes I am able to connect..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to create the second on the wrong server. At a glance, it looks like both of these reside on the same server but are using different server names.

```
data source=myservername;

data source=secondDemoDB
```

Both of those data source lines need to be the same if they are hosted on the same server. The Initial Catalog determines which database on the server that EF will draw from.

Comment: That was a typo...i just changed it to data source=myservername; for both in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I have to declare the same connection string in UI application also. That whole thing was in my DAL library. When i declared the same connection string in my UI application everything worked well..